# Referencing sources in modify interaction instead of collection in OL3

Tags: openlayers

in OL3 Modify and Snapping interactions requires a collection of feature, this collection can be made by appending features from different sources, but when sources  got updated or added, it becomes much difficult to keep the collection synchronized with the sources, as a result we could have false snapping or snapping on past locations of features, it is possible in some way to reference sources in modify interaction instead of collection, is there any idea to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the upcoming v3.7.0 release, you will be able to get a collection of features that is synchronized with a source:

```
var collection = new ol.Collection();
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: collection
});
```

Comment: Great to know! However, I think OP would rather like to know how to merge multiple collections into a single one, which can be used by the `snapping` and the `modify` interactions, and get this merged collection synced with the source collections. Are there any methods or will be in the future releases for this use case?

Comment: Usually you combine `ol.interaction.Modify` and `ol.interaction.Snap` with `ol.interaction.Select`. The Select interaction works against multiple vector layers, and its collection which you get with `ol.interaction.Select#getFeatures()` will contain all selected features from all layers.

Comment: That is a great point, thank you! I would like to add a counterpoint. In a professional WebGIS environment, this is not the preferred behaviour of the product built on OL3. Like in ArcGIS, or QGIS, the modify and the select interactions should be bound to single layers, but the snapping interaction should be applied to multiple layers at a time. Also, it should listen to modifications in the snapping-enabled layers, and add or remove snapping capabilities to newly created or deleted geometries accordingly.